# Trouble inflating second layout

Tags: android, runtime, inflate

I'm trying to set a second inflated layout in my activity, the one that works inflates to set an alarm from a timepicker, the second one inflates a number picker to set an amount. So far the second button will not respond or, based on another set of code (one shown) I get a runtime error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
package org.iimed.www;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.iimed.www.DateTimePicker.DateWatcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CaAdd extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button button_click, amount;
    TextView dateResult, date2;
    int hrs, min;
    int amountt = 0;
    EditText amountedit;
    String amountText;
    Dialog amountdialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datetimeactivity);
        dateResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button_click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setbtn);
        amount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amountbtn);
        amount.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_click.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.setbtn:

            amountdialog = new Dialog(this);

            final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
            // Inflate the root layout
            final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);
            // Grab widget instance
            final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);

            mDateTimePicker.initData();

            Button setDateBtn = (Button) mDateTimeDialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime);
            // Update demo TextViews when the "OK" button is clicked
            setDateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CaAdd.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(CaAdd.this, 2,
                            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                    hrs = mDateTimePicker.getHour();
                    min = mDateTimePicker.getMinute();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

                    mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
                    String result_string = mDateTimePicker.getMonth() + "/"
                            + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getDay()) + "/"
                            + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getYear()) + "  "
                            + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour()) + ":"
                            + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getMinute());

                    if (mDateTimePicker.getHour() > 12)
                        result_string = result_string + "PM";
                    else
                        result_string = result_string + "AM";
                    date2.setText(result_string);

                    mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button cancelBtn = (Button) mDateTimeDialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog);
            // Cancel the dialog when the "Cancel" button is clicked
            cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDateTimePicker.reset();
                    mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Reset Date and Time pickers when the "Reset" button is clicked

            Button resetBtn = (Button) mDateTimeDialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime);
            resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDateTimePicker.reset();
                }
            });

            Button amountbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amountbtn);
            amountbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Inflate the root layout
                    final RelativeLayout amountView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                            .inflate(R.layout.amount, null);
                    // Grab widget instance

                    amountdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                    amountdialog.setContentView(amountView);

                    amountdialog.show();
                    amountedit = (EditText) amountView
                            .findViewById(R.id.amount);
                    ImageButton increase = (ImageButton) amountView
                            .findViewById(R.id.increase);
                    increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            amountt++;
                            amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
                            amountedit.setHint(amountText);
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton decrease = (ImageButton) amountView
                            .findViewById(R.id.decrease);
                    decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            amountt--;
                            amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
                            amountedit.setHint(amountText);

                        }
                    });
                    amountdialog.dismiss();
                    // No title on the dialog window
                    mDateTimeDialog
                            .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    // Set the dialog content view
                    mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);
                    // Display the dialog
                    mDateTimeDialog.show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code so that it's more readable and only contains relevant parts. Also, I don't think you can inflate a second layout in an activity.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a frankenstein, but I'm still learning. If it makes any difference the layout(s) aren't inflating at the same time one dissmisses before the other can happen?

Comment: Well, for one, you should probably redesign this activity. It can't be good to have so much code in one click event handler. It makes it really hard to understand. Second, what's the error you are getting?

Comment: `Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception AndroidRuntimeException)) 
 <VM does not provide monitor information> 
 PhoneWindow.requestFeature(int) line: 286 
 Dialog.requestWindowFeature(int) line: 1062 
 CaAdd$4.onClick(View) line: 136 
 Button(View).performClick() line: 4354 
 View$PerformClick.run() line: 17961`

Comment: `Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725  ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
 Looper.loop() line: 137 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5328 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method] `

Comment: Obviously I don't expect you to waste your time re-writing my code, but is there a short answer on how you'd make it more managable? I've tried to just go by click switch IDs' but then it makes the click within the inflated click a bit convoluted and it goes wrong all over the place.